# How do i randomly swap out the contents of a div

Tags: jquery, css, position

so i'm building a mobile safari iPad app using jquerymobile...

I was using this link as a tutorial...
http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-transitions-javascript/

```
.galleryContainer {
position: fixed;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
}
.galleryContainer-A{
-webkit-transform:translate3d(100px,0px,0px);
}
.galleryContainer-B{
-webkit-transform:translate3d(200px,0px,0px);
}
.galleryContainer-C{
-webkit-transform:translate3d(300px,0px,0px);
}
.galleryContainer-D{
-webkit-transform:translate3d(800px,0px,0px);
}
```

So I can toggle between the original class and galleryContainer-A by doing this...

```
$(".galleryContainer").toggleClass("galleryContainer-A");
```

I want the class to change without having to go back to the original position, how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you shouldn't. The question that comes up in my mind is what is it about the -A class that you want when you toggle it to that class?  If it's a particular style attribute, you should use another class and toggle that.  If it's the benefit of using that selector, again use a different class and go off of that.  The transition is irrevocably tied to that -A class, so if you don't want that transition don't use that class.  Use another separate class in addition to it.

Comment: I basically want that div to move from 1 point to another on a click event. I know you can do this with .animate() but the animation code was running too slowly to be useful. I was hoping to get a speed boost with 3d css transforms which works nicely but I couldn't figure out how to make it jump to multiple positions.

Comment: @Manny Read about css animations http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/webkit-keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: Ah that's what I wanted thanks! 'class="btn galleryContainer"' was actually the part I couldn't figure out.

Comment: Okay just to clarify, I never knew you can add multiple classes to one element. The above animation is solvable if you properly handle add/remove classes.     $(".galleryContainer").removeClass("galleryContainer-A").addClass("galleryContainer-B");